# VNCViewer idle time

Tags: vnc

Is there some way I can ping the vncviewer process or somehow determine the idle time of a vnc session? I know there is a way to make the session automatically disconnect, but I am interested in displaying the idle time.

Comment: Are you trying to do this on the client or server side? What OS is that side running?

Comment: Doesn't matter, I have control of both sides....this is linux